# Запретить выключать фоновую работу приложения

Tags: java, android, kotlin, service, app

Есть android приложение, в котором есть service. Сервис используется для передачи координат, и некоторых запросов. Обнаружилось, что на некоторых смартфонах (Xiamoi, honor), у которых есть своя оболочка ОС, в фоновом режиме сервис перестает работать совсем, или работает некорректно (запросы копятся и отправляются разом раз в 10 минут).
Есть ли способ уберечь себя и своё приложение от такой проблемы?
Вот как объявлен сервис в манифесте:

```
<service
        android:name="com.app.app-loc.presentation.service.MyServiceImpl"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:foregroundServiceType="location"
        android:stopWithTask="false" />
```

Comment: А объявить своё приложение "музыкальным плеером" - не помогает? Просто таким штукам система не должна позволять засыпать надолго - а то у пользователя музыка играть перестанет...

Comment: мысль мне нравится. А где это можно объявить? В манифесте?

Comment: Да, я так понимаю, что это можно сделать в манифесте. Но подробности - Вам придётся погуглить самому, у меня под рукой нет примера...

Comment: @S.H., а не будет ли проверок модерации? Мол суть приложения не соответствует действительности

Comment: По моему, в Андроиде это легитимный сопособ работы приложения в обход фоновой выгрузки... Но я этим занимался очень давно, с тех пор могло что то поменяться. Было бы интереснее выслушать автора вопроса, когда он попробует...

Comment: Как у вас объявлен сервис в манифесте? Есть ли получение геопозиции в сервисе? В каких версиях андроида это наблюдается?

Comment: Дополнил свой вопрос куском кода объявления сервиса в манифесте. Получение геопозиции и есть основная задача сервиса. Про версии андроида точно сказать не могу, проблема наблюдалась на xiaomi mi9 pro, honor 20

Comment: Дело не в Xiamoi https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits

Comment: @Style-7 дело не в редком получение данных местоположения. Даже простой запрос, который должен происходить раз в минуту, не уходит в фоновом режиме. А при выходе телефона "из сна", отправляется пачка таких запросов. При этом на самсунг с20, на планшете леново таких проблем нет.

Comment: Читайте про Doze Mode - все сервисы останавливаются, телефон спит.

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло следующее разрешение в манифесте:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Проблема ушла, теперь всё работает корректно.